# Same kml file on two different servers - one loads in google maps v3 api and the other doesn't. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am migrating a website to a different server/domain name. There is a custom map application that uses Google Maps Javascript API v3. The kml file that it loads works fine on the old server, but not on the new server. To remove all the variables in my own code, i tried it with Google's JS Fiddle of their demo app here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml#try-it-yourself

swapping out the url to the kml file, i first use the old path:

http://nhlt.org/webmap/webmap.xml

it works. Then I put in the new url. The webmap.xml file is exactly the same.

http://groundsw.w17.wh-2.com/webmap/webmap.xml

no data is displayed.

Both of those links are publicly accessible if you just paste them into a browser.

Anyone have any clue what I'm missing?

UPDATE:

This is a screenshot of the results from @geocodezip 's fiddle:
[image: missing link]

Comment: [Both URLs work for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/by5gk08m/).   Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but when I look at your fiddle, I see the first works and the second doesn't as I stated in my question. The second map is showing me some random place in Palo Alto with no pins. The kml files are identical, so the maps should be the same. This is on a completely different computer on a different network (not that it should matter).

Comment: Both maps work for me (show the KML content, and return a KmlStatus of "OK") on this computer/network.  Something is blocking the google server that you are connected to from getting to the second KML file.

Comment: I do see the same behavior you report on my Android phone though.

Comment: I verified the files are identical (even the headers are nearly identical) and the jsfiddle works for me. The only REMOTE possibility I can think of is the hyphen in the domain name. At one point (like 20 years ago), these were invalid. Maybe some code somewhere doesn't like them?

Comment: If i use the secondary url for the nhlt.org site (which also has hyphens), it still works for me: nhltorg0.w15.wh-2.com/webmap/webmap.kml. Mysterious.